# Pass multiple check box values into Controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an Enum list. I create these check boxes with the Enum list dynamically.

Here is the Enum list:

```
[LocalizableDescription(@"BankPos", typeof(Resources.DisplayNames))]
BankPos = 1,
[LocalizableDescription(@"PrarkingPlace", typeof(Resources.DisplayNames))]
PrarkingPlace = 2,
[LocalizableDescription(@"OutdoorPlace", typeof(Resources.DisplayNames))]
OutdoorPlace = 4`
```

I created the check box with `foreach` in Html tag .

Here are the check boxes:

```
<div class="checkbox-container">
    <% foreach (var feature in Model.Features)
        {%>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="q5" />
                <span><%= feature.Text %></span>
            </label>  
        <%} 
    %>
</div>
```

Up to here every thing is fine. My check boxes are create in correctly .

My problem is, how can I pass these check box values into controller?

As I said I want to pass them multiple.

Here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Review(ReviewMemberRatingViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase picUpload)
{
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Your checkboxes don't have a `value` attribute so nothing post back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the checkboxes in your model, and bind the values to them.  So when you change a value on the model, it will be available in your action result.  You could generate your inputs with numerical indexes or there is a great example of what you are doing while taking it a step further with an editor template [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813789/checkboxlist-multiple-selections-difficulty-in-model-bind-back).