# ASP.NET MVC Multiple Checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `List` of about 20 items I want to display to the user with a checkbox beside each one (a `Available` property on my ViewModel).

When the form is submitted, I want to be able to pass the value of each checkbox that is checked back to my controller method via the `Selections` property on my ViewModel.

How would I go about doing this using the Form Helper class in MVC? Is this even possible?

PS: I don't want a listbox where the user can just highlight multiple items.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(x => new MyViewModel
        {
            Id = x
        });
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<MyViewModel> model)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

View `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<AppName.Models.MyViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Editor template `~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/MyViewModel.cshtml`:

```
@model AppName.Models.MyViewModel
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Available)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to create a template that can be reused. I have some code at home that I can post later tonight.

Maybe check SO for similar posts in the mean time.

[Dynamic list of checkboxes and model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234973/asp-net-mvc2-dynamic-list-of-checkboxes-and-model-binding)

Answer (score 0):

This blog post also could help;

http://tugberkugurlu.com/archive/how-to-handle-multiple-checkboxes-from-controller-in-asp-net-mvc-sample-app-with-new-stuff-after-mvc-3-tools-update