# Multiple checkboxes in asp.net mvc 3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm following this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254893/asp-net-mvc-multiple-checkboxes/5256590#5256590), with this code:

SomeControl.cshtml

```
@model Econo.WebUI.ViewModel.UserRoleViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.UserId)

@Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Roles)
```

/Shared/EditorTemplates/Roles.cshtml

```
@model Econo.WebUI.ViewModel.RoleViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.IsInRole)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.RoleId)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.RoleName)
```

For some reason, this only output:

```
<input id="UserId" type="hidden" value="1LS82" name="UserId">
FalseFalse
```

The FalseFalse shows that there are 2 roles in the database and the user is in none of them, which is correct. But I need a checkbox with the ID and Name. Also being able to submit this back to the server to add roles to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partial is wrongly named. It should be `~/Shared/EditorTemplates/RoleViewModel.cshtml` and not `~/Shared/EditorTemplates/Roles.cshtml`. And then:

```
@model Econo.WebUI.ViewModel.RoleViewModel

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsInRole)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RoleName)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RoleId)
```