# MVC 4 - Many-to-Many relation and checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, checkbox, many-to-many

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework. In my database, I have a table **Subscription** which represents a subscription to public transports. This subscription can provide access to several **public transport companies** (so a subscription could have 1, 2, 3, ... companies) then it is a Many-to-Many relation between these tables (I have an intermediate table between them).

I want to allow the creation of a subscription throught a page which will contain a field *Amount* of the subscription and the available companies by checkboxes. Every checkbox represents an existing company (a company stored in my database).

Any idea about how to do that? I've read this [ASP.NET MVC Multiple Checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254893/asp-net-mvc-multiple-checkboxes) but it was not really helpful.

EDIT : Here is my tables diagram.

[image: Tables Diagram]

Comment: are the companies a "fixed" dataset (meaning they will not be modified in this view?)

Comment: Exactly. My companies are stored in my table "companies" and will not be modified here, in the create/edit view.

Comment: You can have a dropdownlist like this: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select)

Comment: No, I'm not looking for a dropdownlist because as I said, a subscription could be composed of 2 or more companies. So that's why I think the checkboxes are better.

Comment: I don't know which view engine you are using but it's not that hard,  you just need to iterate the companies and create the buttons. You might need to change the model class.

Comment: I'm using razor engine. Creating the companies is not that hard yes, but how about the action "create", for example? How can I check which checkboxes are checked and which are not?

Comment: Trying to do with viewmodel, but I can't see how can I get it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You start with two view models. The first one which represents a selected company...

```
public class CompanySelectViewModel
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

...and the second one for the subscription to create:

```
public class SubscriptionCreateViewModel
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CompanySelectViewModel> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the `SubscriptionController`s GET action you load the companies from the database to initialize the view model:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var viewModel = new SubscriptionCreateViewModel
    {
        Companies = _context.Companies
            .Select(c => new CompanySelectViewModel
            {
                CompanyId = c.CompanyId,
                Name = c.Name,
                IsSelected = false
            })
            .ToList()
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Now, you have a strongly typed view for this action:

```
@model SubscriptionCreateViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Companies)

    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index")
}
```

To get the company checkboxes rendered correctly you introduce an editor template. It must have the name `CompanySelectViewModel.cshtml` and goes into the folder `Views/Subscription/EditorTemplates` (create such a folder manually if it doesn't exist). It's a strongly typed partial view:

```
@model CompanySelectViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsSelected, Model.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsSelected)
```

`Name` is added as hidden field to preserve the name during a POST.

Obviously you have to style the views a bit more.

Now, your POST action would look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SubscriptionCreateViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var subscription = new Subscription
        {
            Amount = viewModel.Amount,
            Companies = new List<Company>()
        };

        foreach (var selectedCompany
            in viewModel.Companies.Where(c => c.IsSelected))
        {
            var company = new Company { CompanyId = selectedCompany.CompanyId };
            _context.Companies.Attach(company);

            subscription.Companies.Add(company);
        }

        _context.Subscriptions.Add(subscription);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Instead of using `Attach` you can also load the company first with `var company = _context.Companies.Find(selectedCompany.CompanyId);`. But with `Attach` you don't need a roundtrip to the database to load the companies to be added to the collection.

(**Edit 2**: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17819169/270591) is a continuation for the `Edit` actions and views with the same example model.)

**Edit**

Your model is not really a many-to-many relationship. You have two one-to-many relationships instead. The `PublicTransportSubscriptionByCompany` entity is not needed - normally. If you have a composite primary key in that table made of `Id_PublicTransportSubscription, Id_PublicTransportCompany` and remove the id column `Id_PublicTransportSubscriptionByCompanyId` EF would detect this table schema as a many-to-many relationship and create one collection in each of the entities for subscription and company and it would create no entity for the link table. My code above would apply then.

If you don't want to change the schema for some reason you must change the POST action like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SubscriptionCreateViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var subscription = new Subscription
        {
            Amount = viewModel.Amount,
            SubscriptionByCompanies = new List<SubscriptionByCompany>()
        };

        foreach (var selectedCompany
            in viewModel.Companies.Where(c => c.IsSelected))
        {
            var company = new Company { CompanyId = selectedCompany.CompanyId };
            _context.Companies.Attach(company);

            var subscriptionByCompany = new SubscriptionByCompany
            {
                Company = company
            };

            subscription.SubscriptionByCompanies.Add(subscriptionByCompany);
        }

        _context.Subscriptions.Add(subscription);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think it will help ! I'll try it right now and let you know. However, a little question : the rendering of the partial view will be done automatically with your sample? Thanks again

Comment: @Traffy: Yes, `EditorFor(model => model.Companies)` detects that `Companies` is a collection and renders one partial view per item. Name of the template file (must match the model name) and paths must be exact because MVC searches for the partial view with certain conventions (the usual ones in `Views/{ControllerName}` and in `Shared` etc., but in a subfolder called `EditorTemplates`).

Comment: Okay thanks. Here again, a question : in the post method, you create a new subscription and populate the amount and companies. However, there is no companies list or attribute in my table. Does it matter if I remove it?

Comment: Okay, I see what you want to do. Leave me 2 sec to show you my tables model.

Comment: Here it is. Can you have a look on it?

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be good but only one thing is not working correctly : when I'm doing **PublicTransportSubscriptionByCompany = new List<PublicTransportSubscriptionByCompany>()**, VS says : **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BuSIMaterial.Models.PublicTransportSubscriptionByCompany>' to 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<BuSIMaterial.Models.PublicTransportSubscriptionByCompany>'**

Comment: @Traffy: Oh dear, are you using this out-dated EF stuff with `EntityObject` and no POCOs? You can try to comment out that line. I believe `EntityObject` initializes its navigation collections automatically.

Comment: Thanks ! It works, thanks ! A last question : how should I proceed for an edit please? Thanks again !

Comment: @Traffy: It's a bit more work. You would have similar view models (but including the Id in `SubscriptionEditViewModel`), load the subscription including the ids of the already related companies, load again *all* companies but then set `IsSelected` to `true` for the companies that are already related to the subscription. POST action is more difficult because now you need to delete entities from the link table when the user has unchecked a company and add entities to the link table when the user has checked a new company. Just start and open new questions when you get stuck :)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! But like Traffy, I'd really like to see how this extends to Edit and Delete functionality as well. Could you please show how you would populate your ClassificationSelectViewModel in your Edit controller method to get both the "checked" and "unchecked" values? That's the last part of the puzzle that I'm struggling with.

Comment: @MattFlowers: Somebody asked the same in a new question. The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17819169/270591

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this answer: [Saving Many to Many relationship data on MVC Create view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531769/saving-many-to-many-relationship-data-on-mvc-create-view/11593957#11593957)
If you are doing database first, then just skip to the viewmodel part of section 1.

Answer (score 1):

Just an extension to Slauma's answer. In my case i had to represent many-to-many like a table between Products and Roles, first column representing Products, the header representing Roles and the table to be filled with checkboxes to select roles for product.
To achieve this i have used ViewModel like Slauma described, but added another model containing the last two, like so:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RoleViewModel> Roles { get; set; } 
}
public class RoleViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Next, in Controller we need to fill data:

```
UserViewModel user = new UserViewModel();
user.Name = "Me";
user.Products = new List<ProductViewModel>
                {
                    new ProductViewModel
                    {
                        Id = 1,
                        Name = "Prod1",
                        Roles = new List<RoleViewModel>
                        {
                            new RoleViewModel
                            {
                                Id = 1,
                                Name = "Role1",
                                IsSelected = false
                            }
                            // add more roles
                        }
                    }
                    // add more products with the same roles as Prod1 has
                 };
```

Next, in View:

```
@model UserViewModel@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "User",
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "divContainer"
}))
{
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
            </th>
            @foreach (RoleViewModel role in Model.Products.First().Roles.ToList())
            {
                <th>
                    @role.Name
                </th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Products)
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="Create" value="Create"/>
}
```

As you see, EditorFor is using template for Products:

```
@model Insurance.Admin.Models.ProductViewModel
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
<tr>
    <th class="col-md-2 row-header">
        @Model.Name
    </th>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Roles)
</tr>
```

This template uses another template for Roles:

```
@model Insurance.Admin.Models.RoleViewModel
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsSelected)
</td>
```

And voila, we have a table containing first column Products, the header contains Roles and the table is filled with checkboxes. We are posting UserViewModel and you will see that all the data are posted.