# Preserving navigation properties in Entity Framework when updating without tracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I am developing a program following the Repository pattern which involves a database access with Entity Framework and I have come across a problem. When I try to manipulate the same variable twice in the same context, I am greeted with this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Attaching an entity of type
'Syn.Commons.Data.Tests.EntityFramework.Helper.DbModel.DBBox' failed because 
another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.
This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or [...]
```

I know it comes from the fact that the entity is being used more than once in the same context.  However, when I try to use the `Detach()` method, it loses all of its navigation properties (i.e., all of them <strike>become `null`</strike> **edit: are reset to the last known values**), [as stated here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx) (section Detaching Objects):

```
 In an independent association, the relationship information is not maintained for a detached object.
```

If I were making queries, I would use `AsNoTracking()`, but it is not possible since I am not using them. Here is the `Update()` method:

```
public bool Update(T entity)
{
    // Some code to get dbEnt

    _context.Set<TDbType>().Attach(dbEnt);

    // The following gives an error when manipulating the entity for the second time
    //_context.Entry<TDbType>(dbEnt).State = EntityState.Modified;

    _context.SaveChanges();

    // The following makes the entity "lose" all of its navigation properties
    //DetachEntry(_context.Entry(dbEnt));

    return true;
}
```

It seems that both solutions conflict with each other. Is there any way not to track an entity (without explicit queries) while conserving its navigation properties?

---

**Edit:** people in the comments were right. Although it did no harm, I did not need `Attach()`. Therefore, the method now looks like this:

```
public bool Update(T entity)
{
    // Some code to get dbEnt
    _context.Entry<TDbType>(dbEnt).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: hi, i think this is not fine. the `attach` will removes any update you did and render the model as a brand new from the database - you can check this on the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.attach(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Attach(System.Object)). are you trying to make a manager pattern a top Entity Framework?

Comment: According to the docs the entity should already be there so I thought the method was appropriate. However, if what you are saying is correct, then it makes sense that the navigation properties are lost... And what I am trying to create is a Repository Pattern, I will clarify that in my post.

Comment: Remove this `Update` method entirely. Let EF's change tracking decide whether an entity is modified and save changes in a Unit of Work that should be part of your architecture when using repository pattern.

Comment: if its repository pattern, you can see on [this tutorial on ms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

Entity Framework **does not manage relationships when updating from detached entities** (see the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443221/mvc4-controller-with-many-to-many-relationship) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404672/cleanly-updating-a-hierarchy-in-entity-framework/32407776#32407776) for more details), and so it must be done **by hand**, which is a little sad since relationships are managed by default when adding.

I found a library that was supposed to automatically link the updated relationships on detached entities (which was exactly what I wanted), but I could not seem to make it work. It is called [GraphDiff](https://github.com/zzzprojects/GraphDiff), in case you want to check it out (there are more over there, you can search for them as well).

Thanks to everyone in the comments.

---

**Edit:** after working on it, I have managed to solve my problem by hand. Here is the pseudocode for one-to-many relationships. It is assuming that you have access to your current entity (which I will call `entity`), and that there is a list in such entity that holds the "many" part:

```
var previous = Find_Previous_Entity();

// Find list differences from the database entity (you may need a comparer)
var added = entity.OneToManyList.Except( previous.OneToManyList );  // ToList() optional but very recommended
var deleted = previous.OneToManyList.Except( entity.OneToManyList );  // Same as above

// Make the appropriate changes
foreach( var item in deleted )
{
    item.TheForeignKey = null;  // Foreign key related with the entity
    myContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
foreach( var item in added )
{
    item.TheForeignKey = entity.ThePrimaryKey;
    myContext.Entry(item).State = (item.Id == 0) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
}
```

This should be it. Now, regarding many-to-many relationships it gets a little trickier. What I did was restore the list of the new entity to their original value (the one in the database), `Attach()` the entity to the context so that Entity Framework could track the changes made to the relationships, and then change them:

```
var previous = Find_Previous_Entity();

// Find list differences from the database entity (you may need a comparer)
var added = entity.ManyToManyList.Except( previous.ManyToManyList );  // ToList() optional but very recommended
var deleted = previous.ManyToManyList.Except( entity.ManyToManyList );  // Same as above

// Restore the current list to the value held in the database
entity.ManyToManyList.Clear();
foreach( var item in previous.ManyToManyList )
{
    // You may want to insert the line below to avoid attaching both the previous entity and the current one to the context, it gets messy then
    item.OtherManyToManyList.Remove(previous);
    entity.ManyToManyList.Add(item);
}
// The new entity now has a copy of the previous list

//Attach the entity with the previous list
myContext.Set<ClassOfEntity>().Attach(entity);
// Entity Framework will now acknowledge the changes made in the list and automatically create the appropriate relationships

foreach( var item in deleted )
{
    entity.ManyToManyList.Remove(item);
    myContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
foreach( var item in added )
{
    entity.ManyToManyList.Add(item);
    myContext.Entry(item).State = (item.Id == 0) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
}
```

The many-to-many part is not beautiful, but it works. As you may have noted, if you have many many-to-many (hehe) relationships, you will need to update the current `entity` with all of the lists of `previous`, then call `Attach()` and finally work with the lists.

If you have any other way to do it without "attaching the entity to the context with the previous list", please tell me in the comments, it would be very appreciated. Regardless, I hope it is useful for any of you.