# MVC 4 Edit Controller/ View Many to Many relation and checkboxes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, many-to-many

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework and I was searching for some way to make many to many relation and checkboxes from my db for a Create/Edit controller and view, I have found the answer with @Slauma answer for Create in [MVC 4 - Many-to-Many relation and checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383494/mvc-4-many-to-many-relation-and-checkboxes)  but, I'd really like to see how this extends to Edit and Delete functionality as well like some other partners in this solution. Could someone please show how I would populate the ClassificationSelectViewModel in the Edit controller method to get both the "checked" and "unchecked" values? this is a Matt Flowers question that will solve mine too.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: @Jack: basically the create model/view/controller schema from the link, with some little exceptions and what I need is the Edit method, guess I can't add anything else that you can't see over there

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following is a continuation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16383982/270591) that describes `Create` GET and POST actions for a model with many-to-many relationship between entities `Subscription` and `Company.` Here is the procedure for the `Edit` actions how I would do it (except that I probably wouldn't put all the EF code into the controller actions but extract it into extension and service methods):

The `CompanySelectViewModel` remains unchanged:

```
public class CompanySelectViewModel
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

The `SubscriptionEditViewModel` is the `SubscriptionCreateViewModel` plus the `Subscription`'s key property:

```
public class SubscriptionEditViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CompanySelectViewModel> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

The `GET` action could look like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    // Load the subscription with the requested id from the DB
    // together with its current related companies (only their Ids)
    var data = _context.Subscriptions
        .Where(s => s.SubscriptionId == id)
        .Select(s => new
        {
            ViewModel = new SubscriptionEditViewModel
            {
                Id = s.SubscriptionId
                Amount = s.Amount
            },
            CompanyIds = s.Companies.Select(c => c.CompanyId)
        })
        .SingleOrDefault();

    if (data == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    // Load all companies from the DB
    data.ViewModel.Companies = _context.Companies
        .Select(c => new CompanySelectViewModel
        {
            CompanyId = c.CompanyId,
            Name = c.Name
        })
        .ToList();

    // Set IsSelected flag: true (= checkbox checked) if the company
    // is already related with the subscription; false, if not
    foreach (var c in data.ViewModel.Companies)
        c.IsSelected = data.CompanyIds.Contains(c.CompanyId);

    return View(data.ViewModel);
}
```

The `Edit` view is the `Create` view plus a hidden field for the `Subscription`'s key property `Id`:

```
@model SubscriptionEditViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Companies)

    <input type="submit" value="Save changes" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index")
}
```

The editor template to select a company remains unchanged:

```
@model CompanySelectViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsSelected, Model.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsSelected)
```

And the POST action could be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(SubscriptionEditViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var subscription = _context.Subscriptions.Include(s => s.Companies)
            .SingleOrDefault(s => s.SubscriptionId == viewModel.Id);

        if (subscription != null)
        {
            // Update scalar properties like "Amount"
            subscription.Amount = viewModel.Amount;
            // or more generic for multiple scalar properties
            // _context.Entry(subscription).CurrentValues.SetValues(viewModel);
            // But this will work only if you use the same key property name
            // in ViewModel and entity

            foreach (var company in viewModel.Companies)
            {
                if (company.IsSelected)
                {
                    if (!subscription.Companies.Any(
                        c => c.CompanyId == company.CompanyId))
                    {
                        // if company is selected but not yet
                        // related in DB, add relationship
                        var addedCompany = new Company
                            { CompanyId = company.CompanyId };
                        _context.Companies.Attach(addedCompany);
                        subscription.Companies.Add(addedCompany);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var removedCompany = subscription.Companies
                       .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CompanyId == company.CompanyId);
                    if (removedCompany != null)
                        // if company is not selected but currently
                        // related in DB, remove relationship
                        subscription.Companies.Remove(removedCompany);
                }
            }

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The `Delete` actions are less difficult. In the `GET` action you could load a few subscription properties to display on the delete confirmation view:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    // Load subscription with given id from DB
    // and populate a `SubscriptionDeleteViewModel`.
    // It does not need to contain the related companies

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And in the `POST` action you load the entity and delete it then. There is no need to include the companies because in a many-to-many relationship (usually) cascading delete on the link table is enabled so that the database will take care of deleting the link entries together with the parent `Subscription`:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirm(int id)
{
    var subscription = _context.Subscriptions.Find(id);
    if (subscription != null)
        _context.Subscriptions.Remove(subscription);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for another great answer! I did have to make a small change though. I had to change

data.ViewModel.Companies.ForEach(
    c => { c.IsSelected = data.CompanyIds.Contains(c.CompanyId); });

to

foreach (var c in data.ViewModel.Companies)
{
    c.IsSelected = data.CompanyIds.Contains(c.CompanyID);
}   (Sorry for the bad comment format.)

Comment: @Slauma Hey dumb question what would the code look l ike on the view ( with checkboxes ...  +1 very helpful what i mean is that when using `CompanySelectViewModel` in my view i get **Error**`the model item passed into the dictionary is of type` because it is expecting `SubscriptionEditViewModel`

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle: The checkboxes are `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsSelected)`. The `CompanySelectViewModel` is the model for an *editor template*, not for a normal view. It is described in more detail in the other post about Create (see the link in the first line of my answer above).

Comment: @Slauma I got to fix the `checkboxes` with a `List` instead of `Ienumerable` type explained here **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881093/view-not-passing-ienumerable-of-model/18881644?noredirect=1#comment27896045_18881644**

Comment: @Slauma this may not be to appropriate but can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899681/saving-to-m-2-m-with-checkboxes I'm really struggling understanding how you have done this.

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle: Yes, if you use the appoach in Chris Pratt's answer you must use a List because he renders the checkboxes directly in the main view with a foreach loop. My approach was meant to use an **editor template**. To quote myself from the other answer: "It must have the name **CompanySelectViewModel.cshtml** and goes into the folder **Views/Subscription/EditorTemplates** (create such a folder manually if it doesn't exist)". In that case you can use `IEnumerable` and just `EditorFor(model => model.Companies)` without a foreach loop.

Comment: @Slauma using editortemplates how to arrange checkboxes in 3 columns?

Comment: @Willy: Could you ask this as a separate question? These are layout details that are too far away from the original question above in my opinion. I think it will be more a html question because editor templates are just a piece of html with a few razor expressions embedded.