# Posting Ienumerable Values and Saving to M-2-M Relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, parameter-passing, code-first

*VS'12 KendoUI InternetApplication Template C# asp.net EF Code First*

My Question is how to `pass` both the `Regular` ( are passing now ) values and the `Ienumerable`(passing null) into my `controller` and saving them to the `Databas`e using `EF Code First` in a `Many-2-Many Relationship` manor.

**The Following is what i have tried**

- Main View

  ```
  @model OG.Models.UserProfiles

  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {   

       <div class="editor-field">

          <div class="Containter">
          <div>
               @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
          </div>

               <div class="contentContainer">
               @foreach (var item in Model.Prospects)
               {
                   <table>
                       <tr>
                           <td>
                               @Html.Label("Current Prospects")
                          </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td>
                              @Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>item.ProspectName)
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>
               }

             </div>

           </div>

          <div class="contentContainer2">
               @Html.Partial("_UsersInProspectsDDL", new  OG.ModelView.ViewModelUserInProspects() { Users = Model.UserName })
          </div>

      </div>
  }
  ```
- Partial View

  ```
   @model OG.ModelView.ViewModelUserInProspects

              <label for="prospects">Prospect:</label>
              @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m=>m.Prospects)
                    .Name("Prospects")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px"}) //, id = "countys"})
                    .OptionLabel("Select Prospect...")
                    .DataTextField("ProspectName")
                    .DataValueField("ProspectID")
                    .DataSource(source => {
                        source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Action("GetCascadeProspects", "ChangeUsersInfo")
                                .Data("filterProspects");
                        })
                        .ServerFiltering(true);
                    })
                    .Enable(false)
                    .AutoBind(false)
                    .CascadeFrom("Clients")

  </div>
  ```
- Model for PartialView

  ```
  public class ViewModelUserInProspects
      {
      public string Clients { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<dbClient> AvailableClients { get; set; }
      public string Prospects { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<dbProspect> AvailableProspects { get; set; }

      public string Users { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<UserProfiles> AvailableUsers {get;set;}

      }
  }
  ```
- Main Model

  ```
  Standart SimpleMemberShipUserTable
  ```
- Post Method

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult UsersInProspect(
      [Bind(Include= "ProspectName, ProspectID")]
      UserProfiles userprofiles, ViewModelUserInProspects values, FormCollection form) 
      //<- Trying different things sofar 
  {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {

          //string something = form["Prospects"];
          int prosID = Convert.ToInt16(values.Prospects);
          int  UserID = userprofiles.UserID; // <- THIS VALUE is null atm.
  ```

This is where i need to save both ID's to the EF Generated / Mapped Table. Unsure how.

```
            db.Entry(userprofiles).CurrentValues.SetValues(userprofiles);

            db.Entry(userprofiles).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(userprofiles);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812604/mvc-4-edit-controller-view-many-to-many-relation-and-checkboxes)

- Goes over `ViewModels`
- What `EditorTemplate` are and how to use them
- What the `GET Method` would look like
- What the `Edit View` would look like
- Give you a `View` Example
- What the `Post Method` would look like