# View not passing Ienumerable of Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, parameter-passing, partial-views

**Edit: Removed Partial View to make things simpler. Now I just need to find out why The View isn't Posting the Values**

- ViewModelProspectUsers

  ```
  public class ViewModelProspectUsers
  {

      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string User { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<ViewModelProspectSelect> Prospects { get; set; }

  }
  ```
- ViewModelProspectSelect

  ```
  public class ViewModelProspectSelect
  {

      public int ProspectID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

  }
  ```
- View

  ```
  @model OG.ModelView.ViewModelProspectUsers


  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {

      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

      <h5>Please Select Prospects you wish to assign to this User.</h5>
  ```

-----**HERE is where the partial used to be, these values aren't being posted to the `[Post]` Method**------

-----------------------------------------However they are populating just fine----------------------------------------

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.Prospects)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.ProspectID)


                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Name)

                @Html.EditorFor(x => item.IsSelected)

        }
```

---

```
        @*@Html.Partial("_ShowProspectCheckedForUser", Model.Prospects)*@
        @*@Html.Partial("_ShowProspectCheckedForuser", new OG.ModelView.ViewModelProspectSelect())*@


    <input type="submit" value="Save changes" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index")

}
```

- Post

  ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult UsersInProspect(ViewModelProspectUsers viewModel)
  ```

If i were to look at `viewModel.Prospects(m=>m.isSelected)` //<- this value is Null shouldn't be

My viewmodel Variableis showing Data but not for the Ienumerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with list-type objects, you must reference them with array notation to have the field names generated in a way that the modelbinder can parse them back, i.e:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].SomeProperty)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].SomeProperty)
}
```

In your scenario, you'd be better served by using a view model to contain your list and adding a `Selected` property to the items so that you can track which ones were or were not selected.

```
public class ViewModelProspects
{
    public List<ViewModelProspectSelect> Prospects { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelProspectSelect
{
    // Whatever else you have

    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
@model ViewModelProspects

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Prospects.Count(); i++)
    {
        <label>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Prospects[i].Id)
            @Html.CheckboxFor(m => Model.Prospects[i].Selected, true)
            @Model.Prospects[i].Name
        </label>
    }
}
```

And finally, change your action method signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UsersInProspect(ViewModelProspects model)
```

Then, you can easily get the list of selected ids inside the action with:

```
var selectedIds = model.Prospects.Where(m => m.Selected).Select(m => m.Id)
```

Comment: I changed my Models to encorproate your answer, they list fine ( however unchecked) but somehow `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` is showing up on the line of `@Model.Prospects[i].Name` ideas? - will test the return

Comment: `Name` is just a property I made up to signify the property that holds the text for what you want displayed next to the checkbox.

Comment: Absolutely Awesome, sorry it took me a while to wrap around my head what you were doing. Also is there no way to do this with Ienumerables? you must do list?

Comment: No, it has to be a list. You have to use a standard for loop (rather than foreach) to get Razor to generate the field names properly, which means you need to specify the end of the loop, which requires a count. With an `IEnumerable` that will use up your enumeration and then you can't actually run the loop.