# Saving to m-2-m with checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, checkbox, many-to-many

So i'm trying to use [Slauma's Answer][1]

What i have done so far,

**Model** *ViewModelProspectUsers*

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelUserProspectSelect> Prospects { get; set; }
```

**Model** *ViewModelUserProspectSelect*

```
    public int ProspectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
```

**View** *UserInProspect*

```
@model OG.ModelView.ViewModelProspectUsers

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<div class="container">
    <div class="contentContainer">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        Prospects for User <h3>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.User)</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="contentContainer2">
        <h5>Please Select Prospects you wish to assign to this User.</h5>
        <p></p>

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prospects)

    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save changes" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index")
</div>
}
```

**Editor View** Located under ChangeUserInfo/EditorTemplates/*_ViewModelUserprospectSelect.cshtml*

```
@model OG.ModelView.ViewModelUserProspectSelect

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProspectID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
test
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsSelected, Model.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsSelected)
```

**[Get]** Method *UserInProspect* Action

```
public ActionResult UsersInProspect(int id = 0)
    {
        var data = db.UserProfiles
        .Where(s => s.UserID == id)
        .Select(s => new
        {
            ViewModel = new ViewModelProspectUsers
            {
                Id = s.UserID,
                User = s.UserName
            },
            prospects = s.Prospects.Select(c => c.ProspectID)
        })
        .SingleOrDefault();

        if (data == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        // Load all companies from the DB
        data.ViewModel.Prospects = db.Prospect
            .Select(c => new ViewModelUserProspectSelect
            {
                ProspectID = c.ProspectID,
                Name = c.ProspectName
            })
            .ToList();

        // Set IsSelected flag: true (= checkbox checked) if the company
        // is already related with the subscription; false, if not
        foreach (var c in data.ViewModel.Prospects)
            c.IsSelected = data.prospects.Contains(c.ProspectID);

        return View(data.ViewModel);

    }
```

**[HttpPost]** Method *UserInProspect* Action

```
    public ActionResult UsersInProspect(ViewModelProspectUsers viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var subscription = db.UserProfiles.Include(s => s.Prospects)
                .SingleOrDefault(s => s.UserID == viewModel.Id);

            if (subscription != null)
            {
                // Update scalar properties like "Amount"
                //subscription.Prospects = viewModel.Prospects;
                //subscription. = subscription.
                //List<string> myList = new List<string>();
                //myList = viewModel.Prospects.Cast<String>().ToList();

                //IEnumerable<dbProspect> Isubscription = subscription.Prospects;
                ////or explicit:
                //var iPersonList = (IEnumerable<dbProspect>)myList;


                // or more generic for multiple scalar properties
                // _context.Entry(subscription).CurrentValues.SetValues(viewModel);
                // But this will work only if you use the same key property name
                // in ViewModel and entity

                foreach (var prospect in viewModel.Prospects)
                {
                    if (prospect.IsSelected)
                    {
                        if (!subscription.Prospects.Any(
                            c => c.ProspectID == prospect.ProspectID))
                        {
                            // if company is selected but not yet
                            // related in DB, add relationship
                            var addedProspect = new dbProspect { ProspectID = prospect.ProspectID };
                            db.Prospect.Attach(addedProspect);
                            subscription.Prospects.Add(addedProspect);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var removedProspect = subscription.Prospects
                            .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ProspectID == prospect.ProspectID);
                        if (removedProspect != null)
                            // if company is not selected but currently
                            // related in DB, remove relationship
                            subscription.Prospects.Remove(removedProspect);
                    }
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: When you say *"...my prospects are null"* do you mean `viewModel.Prospects` or `subscription.Prospects`?

Comment: `subscription.Prospects` sorry for not clarifying, I think the issue is that i'm using the list and don't understand how to set my list `viewModel.Prospects` = the Ienumerable `Subscription.prospects`

Comment: Hm, but that looks like a very different problem. You are loading the subscription from the DB *including* the prospects: `subscription = db.UserProfiles.Include(s => s.Prospects)...`. `subscription.Prospects ` must never be `null`, even if there is no prospect in the DB. Then it could be an empty collection, but never `null`. Do you really mean `null`, not "empty collection"???

Comment: Values are nolonger Null. I have made some changes to the code, found that I'm now at `viewModel` ( directly after the Post method begins) i check my values and my `viewModel.ProspectID`'s are 0 `viewModel.Names` are "". But selected values are being Posted correctly. Then I assume because id's are null and don't exist in the Database nothing gets changed.

Comment: Did you actually use the approach in my answer with the editor template? In that case neither the Id nor the Name should be null because I've put them as hidden fields into the view (`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyId)` and `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)`). Or did you use the solution in the second link? The Name does not have a hidden field there, so it's clear that you don't get this value back on POST. However the Id has a hidden field there, so it shouldn't be 0.

Comment: The best i can explain is that i'm not sure how I'm supposed to list All Users with All Prospect in this View / Editor View ( they have seperate models and conflict if i through them all into 1 view ) yet every post i read tells me to do so, and move my editor model into a "Standart naming convention folder". If this could be explained that be great and make a heck of a lot more sense.

Comment: The "editor template" is a file that has the name of the class (the class that has the `IsSelected` property for the checkboxes) plus `.cshtml` extension. You must create a subfolder in your VS project tree: `Views/YourControllerName/EditorTemplates` and add that file to this folder (that's a "standard naming convention" folder). In your main view you just call: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prospects)`. MVC detects that this is a collection, creates a loop automatically and searches for the editor template view to render each individual item in this loop.

Comment: @Slauma Does the above clear this up any - i rewrote it to how i would have done it if i wen't your route instead of Pratt's??? - Sorry I'm still really bad with all my Technical terms as you can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Added Reference to my Controller using
>   OG.Views.ChangeUsersInfo.EditorTemplates;

Remove that again. "EditorTemplates" should not be a namespace.

> Added Editor Template under
>   Views/ChangeUsers/Info/EditorTemplates/ViewModeluserProspectSelect.cs

An "editor template" isn't a C# (`.cs`) code file but a Razor view (`.cshtml`). Move the file `ViewModelUserProspectSelect.cs` to the folder where also `ViewModelProspectUsers.cs` is and change its namespace to the same for both classes (`OG.Models`).

(Why is there a subfolder `/Info/` in the path??? Or is it a typo and just `Views/ChangeUsersInfo/EditorTemplates` is meant? I assume that the controller has the name `ChangeUsersInfoController`, right?)

Then create a new file `ViewModelUserProspectSelect.cshtml` in the `Views/ChangeUsersInfo/EditorTemplates` folder that contains the view from the other answer, this one:

```
@model OG.Models.ViewModelUserProspectSelect

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProspectID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsSelected, Model.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsSelected)
```

And the `contentContainer2` div element in your main view should look like this:

```
<div class="contentContainer2">
    <h5>Please Select Prospects you wish to assign to this User.</h5>

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Propects)
</div>
```

Comment: Alright, Code changed and compiles, and thanks so much for taking your time to help me. When this runs in the view I see 1234 i would assume its actually 1,2,3,4 ( but no spaces showing the names of each Prospect, however no checkboxes show, ideas?)

Comment: @Pakk: What is 1,2,3,4??? The PropectIDs of 4 propects in the collection? You shouldn't see those numbers at all because the IDs are rendered with a `HiddenFor`. To check if the editor template is found by MVC you could write a static text "Test" into the template. You should see it then as often as you have items in the Propects collection.

Comment: So i've put Text inbetween the code and I have even commented it all out, saved reloaded nothing change. Thought that was weird so i re-built the app and ran it, same, no change. Now im confused, ill update the code above. Also how can one step through the Editor Templates? it won't let me hit the Breakpoint - no Symbols have been added?

Comment: @Pakk: In your edited question you've written `_ViewModelUserprospectSelect.cshtml`. The editor template must not have an underscore at the beginning (it must have the same name as the class).

Comment: Awesome, that was it so sorry and thanks for the Editor Template walk through as well as your help to your code, fantastic to now be able to write M-2-M tables, i thank you alot!

Comment: @Pakk: Oh, thanks for the bounty! It wasn't really necessary :) Hopefully you came you a few steps forward...

Comment: You are welcome! You have no idea how much it helped :) , i didn't step lol i leaped, Thanks!! - btw this helped me understand a lot thus why i felt to give you some extra points.